# XML file should be read and store in java object to use throughout application on spring mvc

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

I have a xml file which is having all SQL queries. While Application Context gets loaded, from the servlet, I read the file and store it in HashMap which is static and will use that object throught the application.

Now , I migrate to spring mvc . I included the sql xml in resourced folder . I need help to read and use that resource throught the application. Is there any way to handle this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the structure of your file. But what I can suggest is to convert your xml file into an object `UnMarshalling`, then depending on your needs do whatever with that object. There are a lot of good tutorials out there.

Comment: Thank you. I can unmarshall the object by having that logic in a class as I have this at this point of time. 
But I need what else needs to changed if we move to spring. Do we need to use the config class which we usually create with @configuration annotation?

Comment: Can I have a look at the structure of your `sql xml` file?

Comment: <sql>
<db2>
<query code="Filename_method"">
Select * from tablename;
</query>
</db2>
</sql>

Comment: I see. Just define a bean with `@Component` annotation. Inside it, define your your methods to retrieve and populate all your objects. Declare a `@Configuration` bean to define your `UnMarshalling` logic and Now, whenever you need that object, use `@Autowired` on the first class and call your methods to get your objects.